# When your inheriting a class how do you apply information from the base class?

Tags: vb.net

How do you apply a base class to a child inherited class?

ex

```
public class modifiedprocess
inherits process
    public property PCname as string =""
    sub new(pc as process)
        me = pc
        me.pcname=pc.processName
    end sub
'does not not work because me cannot be target, so even though this is 
basically a process with all of properties and methods it will not fill in 
matching data, how do i get it to do that'

end class
```

Comment: You can't do "me = pc", now you have to ask, do you really want inheritance or a class that contains a Process. If you want inheritance, you'll have to set each property or call the MyBase.New().

Comment: in this case, im adding more properties to process, in the example i want it to fill in all data from process

Comment: If you want the properties of the current object to be equal to the properties of some other object then you simply have to assign each one individually. Another option would be to use something like AutoMapper, but this is not the type of scenario that such a tool is intended for. Failing that, you could use Reflection in a loop.